# Jquery load page with chitika ad , breaks site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a header.php file that is included on every single page of my website and what i wanted is to load another php file that included my ad code for my website so I did and for somereason it will load it then redirect me to a blank page with just the ad on it ? please tell me if there is something wrong with my code thank you! here is a link to my website as well, as soon as it loads it redirects you... http://www.quickdailylaugh.com

This is the code to load it into the div.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#contentforads').load('<?php print $actual_link ?>/ads.php').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    </script>
```

This is the code on the ads.php file

```
<style type="text/css">
.leftad{
float:left;
margin-left:30px;
}
.rightad{
float:right;
margin-right:30px;
}
</style>
<div class="leftad"><script type="text/javascript">
  ( function() {
    if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
    var unit = {"publisher":"hidden","width":120,"height":600,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
    var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
    window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
    document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = '//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js';
    try { document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s); } catch(e) { document.write(s.outerHTML); }
}());
</script></div>
<div class="rightad">right ad</div>
```

Comment: Check out [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) on `document.write`.

Comment: i added document open above the function and still doesnt work

Comment: Ah, what I meant is that it's entirely the wrong function. `document.write` wipes the page and outputs new HTML. What you need is something like innerHTML, or append.

Comment: how how would i do it ? how do i append it

Comment: it worked ! i appended it !

Comment: if you answer the question ill check it off for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the function `document.write` you are wiping out and replacing the HTML of your page. Instead, use the JS function `.append` or `.innerHTML` to add content to the existing div `contentforads`.